# set factor levels in ggplot with changing values based on slider bar in r markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a shiny app that sequentially displays points and paths based on a date which is controlled by a slider bar. The `ggplot` color aesthetic is mapped to a factor indicating season (winter, summer, none). If all the points are plotted outside of `shiny` and without a slider bar then the red points are summer, blue points are winter, and white points are none.

However, within `shiny`, as the slider bar is moved and points are added, the color changes, presumably because as more levels of the season factor are added the factor level also changes.

Is it possible to set the color legend to have all levels of the season factor no matter how many points are displayed and also specify the color so that red = summer, blue = winter, and white = none? Said differently, when the `shiny` app opens (and only two points and a single path are shown), I want all levels of season displayed in a legend that does not change as points are added.

The data look like this and are included below using `dupt`.

```
  AcquisitionStartTime GPSUTMNorthing GPSUTMEasting             PosiGMT Season
1  2013.02.09 00:00:00        4947787        600201 2013-02-09 00:00:00 winter
2  2013.02.09 06:00:00        4947945        600910 2013-02-09 06:00:00 winter
5  2013.02.10 00:00:00        4947957        600911 2013-02-10 00:00:00 winter
6  2013.02.10 06:00:00        4947954        600907 2013-02-10 06:00:00 summer
8  2013.02.10 18:00:00        4947797        601052 2013-02-10 18:00:00 summer
9  2013.02.11 00:00:00        4947835        601038 2013-02-11 00:00:00 summer
```

My reproducible `shiny` app is below.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)


shinyApp(
  ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("GPS Data Summary"),
    sliderInput(inputId = "Date",
                label = "Sequance of Observations",  
                min = as.Date(min(dat$PosiGMT)), max = as.Date(max(dat$PosiGMT)),
                value = as.Date(min(dat$PosiGMT))),
    #animate = animationOptions(interval=75, loop=T)),
    plotOutput("PointPlot")
  ),

  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$PointPlot <- renderPlot({
      p <- ggplot(dat[as.Date(dat$PosiGMT) <= input$Date ,], 
                  (aes(x = GPSUTMEasting, y = GPSUTMNorthing ))) + 
        geom_point(aes(color = Season), size = 2) + geom_path(aes(color = Season)) + 
        scale_color_manual(values = c("white" ,"red","blue"), labels = c("Spring/Fall", "Summer","Winter"))+
                xlim( min(dat$GPSUTMEasting), max(dat$GPSUTMEasting))+
        ylim( min(dat$GPSUTMNorthing), max(dat$GPSUTMNorthing))
      print(p)
    })
  }

)
```

Data

```
dat <- structure(list(AcquisitionStartTime = structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 
                                                  6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("2013.02.09 00:00:00", 
                                                                                                   "2013.02.09 06:00:00", "2013.02.09 12:00:00", "2013.02.09 18:00:00", 
                                                                                                   "2013.02.10 00:00:00", "2013.02.10 06:00:00", "2013.02.10 12:00:00", 
                                                                                                   "2013.02.10 18:00:00", "2013.02.11 00:00:00", "2013.02.11 06:00:00", 
                                                                                                   "2013.02.11 12:00:00", "2013.02.11 18:00:00", "2013.02.12 00:00:00", 
                                                                                                   "2013.02.12 06:00:00", "2013.02.12 12:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
               GPSUTMNorthing = c(4947787L, 4947945L, 4947957L, 4947954L, 
                                  4947797L, 4947835L, 4947825L, 4947784L, 4947842L, 4947839L, 
                                  4947789L), GPSUTMEasting = c(600201L, 600910L, 600911L, 600907L, 
                                                               601052L, 601038L, 601031L, 601066L, 600998L, 600995L, 601058L
                                  ), PosiGMT = structure(c(1360393200, 1360414800, 1360479600, 
                                                           1360501200, 1360544400, 1360566000, 1360587600, 1360630800, 
                                                           1360652400, 1360674000, 1360695600), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                          "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Season = c("winter", "winter", "winter", 
                                                                                                                                             "summer", "summer", "summer", "None", "None", "None", "None", 
                                                                                                                                             "None")), .Names = c("AcquisitionStartTime", "GPSUTMNorthing", 
                                                                                                                                                                  "GPSUTMEasting", "PosiGMT", "Season"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                       5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Set the factor levels to include all possible values, whether present or not in the data subset, then add `drop=FALSE` to `scale_colour_manual` as discussed in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34950563/496488).

Comment: perfect.  thanks.  maybe a duplicate... or post as answer...

Comment: I think it's basically a duplicate, just with the additional nuance of dynamic subsetting.

Comment: Yea. the additional info I included clouded my real issue which is answered elsewhere, as you indicated.